# Using Jquery function in blazor application without button click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, razor, blazor-server-side

i am new to .net core and blazor but experimenting, but struggling to be able to implement a what would be simple jquery call in mvc...

So i have a jquery method in a js file called selfWritingText.js

```
$("#typed").typed({
        strings: ["LOADING RECORDS...", "ONE MOMENT PLEASE...", ""],
        typeSpeed: 60,
        startDelay: 0,
        backSpeed: 40,
        backDelay: 500,
        loop: true,
        cursorChar: "|",
        contentType: 'html'
    });
```

I have added the call in my host file

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
<script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/interop.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/SelfWritingText.js"></script>
```

Now in my razor page, i add the `@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime`.

```
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        this.VisibleProperty = true;
        await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("selfWritingText");
        await LoadData();
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        this.VisibleProperty = false;
    }
```

And my html where the jquery should be called

```
 <SfSpinner @bind-Visible="@VisibleProperty" Type="@SpinnerType.Bootstrap" Size="50" CssClass="e-customClass">

                                            @*<h3 style="font-family:open sans,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#298282">LOADING....</h3>
                                                <br />*@
                                            <div class="type-wrap">
                                                <!-- add static words/sentences here (i.e. text that you don't want to be removed)-->
                                                <span id="typed" style="white-space:pre;" class="typed">
                                                </span>
                                            </div>

                                        </SfSpinner>
```

But i just get these errors can anybody tell me what im doing wrong.. thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you call the InvokeVoidAsync method via IJSRuntime, it will search the method inside the "window" object (a object that represent an open window in a browser).

try to write your method in this way inside the javascript file you created:

```
window.selfWritingText = () => {                                    
   $("#typed").typed({
    strings: ["LOADING RECORDS...", "ONE MOMENT PLEASE...", ""],
    typeSpeed: 60,
    startDelay: 0,
    backSpeed: 40,
    backDelay: 500,
    loop: true,
    cursorChar: "|",
    contentType: 'html'
});}
```

Then, remember that javascript method could not be called inside the  OnInitializedAsync Method or you will get an exception!
JavaScript interop calls can only be performed during the OnAfterRenderAsync lifecycle method.

And also remember to put your js file inside the _host.chstml file!

```
    <script src="~/selfWritingText.js"></script>
```